# Creating a new data.frame variable using sample(), with maximum sample() value differing by row

Tags: r, dataframe, random, iteration, conditional-operator

I have a data frame of 12071 rows `foo`. I am trying, for each row of `foo`, to generate a single random value based on 1:K, and insert it into a new column, L. For example, the first row should give a L value of between 1 and 5, the second should give a value between 1 and 9, the third between 1 and 3, and so forth. These values must be integers, hence my attempts to use `sample()`. There is an equal probability of selection for any integer in the range, within each row.

I have cut down the number of columns in the code, as they are irrelevant, and I'm having problems with data wrapping in the example. The columns A and K are linked, so that the string in column A always has the same value in column K. There are duplicate A/K combinations as the column A values are not unique.

Data (columns reduced):

```
A           B     C     D               E     F             G       ... K    
A011100     F     7     Partnered       4     40-49 Hrs     0.04075     5
A011200     M     7     Partnered       4     40-49 Hrs     0.13334     9
A011400     F     8     Non-partnered   2     30-39 Hrs     0.02310     3
A011500     F     4     Non-partnered   4     1-9 Hrs       0.94519     4
A012100     M     8     Partnered       4     40-49 Hrs     0.78114     4
```

I can't get my code to work. I can't work out the logic to pass a new maximum value to `sample()`, for each row in the data.frame, and have it constructed correctly in each row.

I have tried the following:

```
foo$L <- lapply(foo, sample(1:foo$K,1))
```

That gave:

> Error in match.fun(FUN) : 
>       'sample(1:foo$K, 1)' is not a function, character or symbol
>       In addition: Warning message:
>       In 1:foo$K :
>       numerical expression has 12071 elements: only the first used

then

```
foo$L <- lapply(foo, function(x) sample(1:foo$K,1))
```

and the error from that was:

> Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, L, value = list(A = 1L,  : 
>       replacement has 12 rows, data has 12071
>       In addition: There were 12 warnings (use warnings() to see them)

then

```
foo$L <- replicate(nrow(foo), sample(foo, 1:foo$K,1))
```

and that gave

> There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can do `sample` using `sapply`

```
df$L <- sapply(df$K, function(x) sample(x, 1))

#        A B C K L
#1 A011100 F 7 5 1
#2 A011200 M 7 9 7
#3 A011400 F 8 3 2
#4 A011500 F 4 4 2
#5 A012100 M 8 4 1
```

As taken from `?sample`

> If x has length 1, is numeric (in the sense of is.numeric) and x >= 1, sampling via sample takes place from 1:x.

So for every value of `df$K` we sample it from `1:x` in `sapply` and then select one of those value randomly.

PS - I have further reduced the columns just for simplicity and better visibility.

Answer (score 2):

I think Ronak Shah's answer is better than mine, but for a `dplyr` solution, try:

```
library(dplyr)

desired_df <- mutate(rowwise(foo), L = sample(K,1))
```

Output:

```
A           B     C     D               E     F             G           K     L 
A011100     F     7     Partnered       4     40-49 Hrs     0.04075     5     4
A011200     M     7     Partnered       4     40-49 Hrs     0.13334     9     7
A011400     F     8     Non-partnered   2     30-39 Hrs     0.02310     3     1
A011500     F     4     Non-partnered   4     1-9 Hrs       0.94519     4     3
A012100     M     8     Partnered       4     40-49 Hrs     0.78114     4     1
```

Comment: Thank you for the dplyr example, which is nice and simple. I'm trying to stay away from adding in additional packages (I have so many!), and I'm sure your example will be helpful to those using dplyr. The joy of R, so many different ways to do the same thing!